# What's wrong with my SSD storage size?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd, gparted

Gparted shows that the sda3 part used 200GB and 692GB available, but the df -h shows that the part mounted on / is 12GB used and 175G available.
The df -h also shows that there are some strange parts cost much space of my disk. Such as tmpfs and Filesystem.
[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNJtj.png)

[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrddB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

Your sda3 is a part of LVM volume group. 200GB of that volume group is assigned to a logical volume which is mounted as your `/`. You can expand logical volume using unused space in a volume group.

Have a look at output of these commands
`sudo pvs`, `sudo vgs`, `sudo lvs`. `pvs` will show you that sda3 belongs to a VG `ubuntu-vg`. `vgs` will show those 690GB available and 200 GB allocated for that VG. And `lvs` will show you have a logical volume `ubuntu-lv` allocated from VG `ubuntu-vg`.

`df` is showing actual filesystem allocation on your `ubuntu-lv` logical volume.